# How do I make search results appear on same page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, search-form

Just a heads up- I just learned Ruby on Rails a few months ago, so this might be a completely ignorant question, but here it goes...

I have this working properly in my "Show" view

```
  <%= form_tag search_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag('query', '', :size => 12, :class => "input-small search-query", :placeholder =>"Search") %>
  <% end %>
```

It redirects to the search_path partial I created in the same view. Can I render this partial on the same page? I want the search results to show on the same page as the search bar, rather than redirect to another page.

Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't understand this: "It redirects to the search_path partial I created in the same view." Can you show us your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an ajax form because you probably want to stay on the same page with the form and it's search results:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html